# compiling ffmpeg 2.3 for android with NDK r10 on windows

Tags: android, windows, android-ndk, ffmpeg

After a week i'm trying to compile ffmpeg for android.
I can't find a static build in the entire web exept for https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg-java/tree/master/res/raw but is 0.11 version one.

This is my build.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NDK=C:/Android/android-ndk-r10
SYSROOT=$NDK/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/
TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/windows-x86_64

function build_one
{
./configure \
    --arch=arm \
    --target-os=linux \
    --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
    --enable-pic \
    --disable-shared \
    --enable-static \
    --extra-cflags='-march=armv6' \
    --extra-ldflags="$ADDI_LDFLAGS" \
    --enable-ffmpeg \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-ffserver\
    --disable-network \
    --enable-cross-compile \
    --cross-prefix=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- \
    --sysroot=$SYSROOT \
    $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_FLAG
make clean
make -j4
make install
}

CPU=arm
PREFIX=$(pwd)/android/$CPU
ADDI_CFLAGS="-marm"

build_one
```

It seems everything works good except the compilation stopped after 4 files:

[image: ffmpeg]

It seems to stay here forever. After 4 hours nothing is moving.
the process "make.exe (32 bit)" is running with 18% of cpu

Any help will be precious.
Thank u

Answer (score 1):

I have compiled FFMpeg from Guardian project [here](https://github.com/android-native-libraries/android-ffmpeg) for all architecture. feel free to use the library files.

Comment: Was it on windows? Please do mention that. The question specifically tells that the build failed on Windows.